# Need Create Category API for OroCommerce

Tags: api, rest, orocrm, orocommerce

**Hi All,
We are searching for create category OroCommerce API. same not showing in API doc.**

[screenshot of available API for category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt9LH.png)

Regards
Satish

Answer (score 0):

You are browsing the OroCommerce Storefront API Sandbox, where categories are exposed as read-only.

To manipulate categories, you have to use the Back-Office API & Sandbox, that is accessible by `http://<hostname_of_your_oro_application>/admin/api/doc` URL.

For more details, see the [OroCommerce API Sandbox documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/sandbox/)

Comment: Hi Andrey in API Sandbox documentation we found only GET, we are searching for POST.

Comment: There are two sandboxes, the admin/api/doc has the POST method for products

Comment: Hi Andrey we are searching post method for category. and will you please share two sandboxes details.

Comment: Please, check the above documentation, it explains "two sandboxes details"

Comment: Hi Andrey checked both sandboxes but POST method not found.